# How to access associated rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 Models Expense, Revenue and Profit. These models belongs to Estate such that estate has one expense revenue and profit. Estate belongs to user such that user has many estate. So what should I write in the index and create method of controller of Expense, Revenue and Profit So only those models are shown which are associated with that particular estate. (like there is current_user method provided by devise. In this case I use to associate estate with User @estates = Estate.where(:user_id => current_user.id))

So do I have to create new current_expense, current_revenue and current_profit methods ? How do I create it and where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about for the expense index html.erb

```
current_user.estates.each do |estate|
  estate.expenses.each do |expense|
    expense.value
  end
end
```

for the create action i like to use the gem simple_form here is a railscast for it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/234-simple-form

and this is what i do:

new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for [@estate,@expense] do |f| %>

        <%= f.input :value1 %>
        <%= f.input :value2 %> 

<% end %>
```

controller

```
def create
    respond_to do |format|      
      if @expense.save
        format.html { redirect_to @expense, notice: '@expense was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I dont think so you got my question. Maybe I explained it poorly. When I log on with any user.. that user can see all revenues expense or net profit. But I want that user should be able to see revenue expense or net profit just belonging to his estates only. so do I make it possible ?

Comment: thats what i understand... the current user will only be able to see the info related to his estates here is where that magic happends:
current_user.estates.each do |estate|

Comment: But when saving the expense, how will take the value of foreign key that is estate_id in the expense table ?

Comment: <%= simple_form_for [@estate,@expense] do |f| %>

in this block you are telling your app that expense has a relation with estate

Comment: so there is no need of adding estate_id column in expense table ?

Comment: rails will do it automaticly, just make sure your relations are right and the migratons for each table has the apropriate fields